# Using another procedure instead of using main() directly

Tags: c, gcc, arm

In the nxp CMSIS examples, instead of writing code in the body of main procedure, we call another procedure like this:

```
int c_entry(void)
{
       //code Entry
    while(1);
    return 1;
}

int main (void)
{
    return c_entry();
}
```

I think we just loose a memory and I'm wondering to know what is the advantage of this kind of coding?

thanks

Comment: what "memory" do you loose? BTW, I find this style useless, except maybe for when you have to call the main function more than one time (which is a rare case).

Comment: Somebody took the advice to keep `main` small very very seriously. I don't see any advantage to that.

Comment: @akappa, it would be useless for that, too, in C.

Comment: For small programs the benefits may not be immediately obvious, but for medium to large real-world programs it's good practice to just have command line processing in main end devolve everything else down to other functions.

Comment: some toolchains will link in extra stuff to your binary that you may not be using if you have the function named main().  I have not seen it in a while but at the same time I cannot afford those compilers anymore.  never-the-less I always use some other function name as my C entry point for embedded (and use my own bootstrap/loader to call that function).  In theory main should not be magic other than perhaps hardcoded in the bootstrap code if you use the stock code.

Comment: Thank you guys for your replies. @akappa we should store our address in the stack for returning to main function.

Comment: @MohammadYousefi: lol, I don't think that's something you have to bother about.

Answer (score 0):

> I think we just loose a memory

Not as much as you might think. The compiler can optimize the tail call to a Jump - so there would be no additional stack usage - or it can even auto-inline the c_entry function. At least GCC is able to do that in higher optimization levels.